# slideToggle conflict in table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle

I need to display some data on click of an icon in a table. My problem is that only the first tr is affected.

Below **my html code**

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Request)
       {
         <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestContent)
            </td>
              
               <td>
               <a href="#" class="showExtra"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> 
               </a>
               <a href="#" class="showReplies"><i class="fas fa-info"></i> 
               </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="extra" style="display:none">
                    extra
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="replies" style="display:none">
                <div> replies</div>
               </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
       }
```

And my **script code**

```
 <script>
        $(".showReplies").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".replies").slideToggle("slow");
        })

    
        $(".showExtra").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".extra").slideToggle("slow");
        })
    </script>
```

I need to hide/show each tr according to the corresponding click. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: are there multiple rows with extra and replies classes and are there multiple tables for same functionality? If yes, then can you update your post to include such structure

Comment: no there is one table with many rows that all have to show some extra infos

Comment: ok.. so in that case you should be able to achieve the solution as per Chaska has provided

Comment: thank you for your comment. It seems to work but now my problem is that I have many rows and data which are opening all at once. Any idea?

Comment: can you add the HTML in your post wtih multiple such rows and explain the expected behaviour of it so that i can take a look at it

Comment: well the rows in my table are loaded dynamically from db. I use .net core

Comment: ok... but what exact behavior you are expecting with these multiple rows... it would be good if you can explain it with relevant html

Comment: multiple rows are display my data. I have some extra field and info per record which I need to open it with toggle function.

Comment: @touinta, please check the answer i have posted. Please correct if any syntatical error as i am not much aware of C# language. let me know if that works or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are always searching `.extra` and `.replies` in the 2nd `<tr>`. Change the code as below. Find them in `table` instead.

```js
$(".showReplies").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("table").find(".replies").slideToggle("slow");
})

$(".showExtra").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("table").find(".extra").slideToggle("slow");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="showExtra">Show Extra</a>
      <a href="#" class="showReplies">Show Replies</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="extra" style="display:none">
        extra
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="replies" style="display:none">
        <div> replies</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. It seems to work but now my problem is that I have many rows and data which are opening all at once. Any idea?

Comment: You may consider separate them to different tables

Answer (score 0):

you can put logic to have id each div for `showExtra` and `showReplies` and attached it to the anchor tag with `data-div-id` attribute.
On click of anchor tag, you can hide all extra and replies div and show the relevent extra or replies on the basis of `data-div-id` value of clicked anchor.

See below example (please correct @i where i have used to generate unique id for each div as i am not much aware of C# syntax)

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.Request)
       {
           <tr>
               <td>
               <a href="#" class="showExtra"><i class="fas fa-plus" data-div-id="extraDiv@i"></i> 
               </a>
               <a href="#" class="showReplies"><i class="fas fa-info" data-div-id="repliesDiv@i"></i> 
               </a>
            </td>
          </tr>


   
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="extra" style="display:none" id="extraDiv@i">
                    extra
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="replies" style="display:none" id="repliesDiv@i">
                <div> replies</div>
               </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
       @{i++;}
       }
```

Add script as below and show / hide as per the relevant id of clicked showReplies and showExtra

```
<script>
        $(".showReplies").click(function () {
            //hide all replies and extras -- you can remove this if not required
            ('div[id^=repliesDiv]').hide();
            ('div[id^=extraDiv]').hide();
            //show relevent div
            var divId = $(this).data('div-id');
            $('#' + divId).show();
        })

    
        $(".showExtra").click(function () {
            //hide all replies and extras -- you can remove this if not required
            ('div[id^=repliesDiv]').hide();
            ('div[id^=extraDiv]').hide();
            var divId = $(this).data('div-id');
            $('#' + divId).show();
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...it needs @(i) so the increament to work. But it doesn't work. It works only for extra and no for replies

Comment: it should work for both....can you check if any console error or ids getting generared correctly

Comment: Yes I receive 'div[id^=repliesDiv7]".hide is not a function'